# 2 out of 3 sets of (black) wires in receptacle are hot

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, gfci, grounding

I am trying to replace old receptacles in my 1952 home.
None of the receptacles have ground wires, so I am replacing the first ones on the line to protect the ones connected to the load using a GFCI receptacle.
However, i found that one of the receptacles has three sets of wires, and no ground. the receptacle boxes are all metal.
Two of the black wires are connected to one screw, and same for the white wires. and then there is one white and one black that have their own screw.
The green ground I drew is not a real ground, whoever installed it connected a very small copper wire back stabbed to the bottom neutral side.

Am i able to wire nut one set of wires that is load, and one that is line together? The third set (also line) going directly to the receptacle.
I am unsure at this time if the two line sets are separate breakers. if they are, does that make a difference in my question of wire nutting a line and load together, and having the other line go directly to the receptacle with no loads attached?

Thanks!

I attempted a diagram [image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that my non contact tester beeped at two out of the three black (hot) wires
The tab on the original receptacle is not broken off. But if it was, would that make a difference in voltage?

Comment: The tab should connect both screws as one connection.  Broken tabs could mean a switched outlet half or top/bottom are on two different circuits.  Most common outlet screws are one wire per screw, there are better(more expensive) outlets that allow two wires.

Comment: connecting ground to neutral or neutral to ground is a very bad hack.  With metal boxes it does not hurt to test if the box is grounded with a meter.  Neutral to box might read 0v or hot/black to box should read 120v if grounded box.

Comment: Two blacks reading hot and one not is a problem if the tab is connected.  Non contact testers are only good to let you know not to stick fingers/tongues in there.  You need a meter to test well and find what is happening.

Comment: I will do so tomorrow and report back on the voltage, as well as check if the metal box provides ground